# Webcomic about a newborn aging too fast without stopping

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

I am trying to find a really *short* webcomic (only a few pages long) that I read I think around 5 years ago on the Internet.

If I remember correctly the setting, it was about a doctor and his assistant who were present during a childbirth doing their jobs like usual. However the child, once brought to the world starts aging at an extraordinary rate, growing and getting close to 80 years old in just a few minutes.

The doctor, seeing as it was an unprecedented event decides to observe the phenomenon to see how humans would look like if they could live after a few centuries.

> In the last panel, the newborn has now become a grotesque mass of flesh getting close to a few millennia old.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds partially like Junji Ito's "Nagai Yume", although I don't recognise the bit about the childbirth.

In the story, a patient suffers from increasingly long dreams, in which he lives for longer and longer periods of time. In the waking world, his body ages rapidly (but without deteriorating) as if he actually lived those lives, but much faster (since dreams happen faster than real time).

At the end,

> the patient becomes a grotesque creature, and the doctor decides to keep studying him as well as making another patient suffer the same condition.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagai_Yume

Comment: Close but unfortunately not that one.